# Clojure macros and symbol binding

Tags: macros, clojure, symbols

not sure how to express this..

I've written a macro which takes two arguments. The first one essentially contains identifiers for generating a let expression. The second is the code to use inside the let expression (it wants to have access to these identifiers).

An example:

```
(match (Add {ast-> x}) (println x))
```

When the second argument is raw code, things work nicely. x binds to the x defined in the let expression (when macroexpanded it just shows as x). However, when the second argument is a macro which generates (println x), x expands to something like user/x.

Any good ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your second macro is defined as:

```
(defmacro foo
  []
  `(println x))
```

This is incorrect as `x` will be namespace qualified.  The correct version of the second macro in this case would be:

```
(defmacro foo
  []
  `(println ~'x))
```

Now the `x` in the `println` call will be a literal x symbol and not namespace qualified.